# Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried running the app I created in android studio 2.3.3 using genymotion android emulator, but there was an error. The Error says this

> Error: Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: CreateProcess error
>   = 5, Access is denied

Previously I've used genymotion android emulator to run apps made in android studio and have no problem. But this time there is an error like the above, I think this is not from the code I use

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it is caused because of my security application, happens by blocking some gradle operation ...informing as ransomware.

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem; it was antivirus software blocking some android studio binaries .

Answer (score 0):

Yes in my case it is caused by AVG antivirus program blocking some operation, uninstall it works for me